# rfind and << crashing program

Tags: c++

I have a problem that has a few programmers pulling their hair. The language is C/C++. Consider the code below...assume *request* is a valid C++ string.

```
string outMsg;
string trans_str = ("</TRANSACTION>");
int32_t position;

//Assign outMsg and find "</TRANSACTION>"
outMsg.assign(request);
position = outMsg.rfind(trans_str);
```

The program crashes on the rfind(trans_str). The program also crashes when find(...) and replace(...) is used. It seems it has trouble with most C++ methods. The program also crashes on lines like the following....

```
cout << "This is a string " << variable << "and this is the end"; //this is an example
```

The program usually crashes on the third "<<" and would only print the following output in this example:

"This is a string {variable} " CRASH.

A lot of weird things going on here.

"string" (in angle brackets) is included.

Thank you!

Comment: "*The language is C/C++.*" /facepalm

Comment: Why are some programmers such smart asses?

Comment: C and C++ are entirely different languages that happen to resemble each other in some ways. What you have here has nothing to do with C.

Comment: I suspect that the problem happens before this code. I.e. that `request` is not, in fact, a valid string.

Comment: Are you able to use a debugger to analyze your program? Specifically, what is the value of `this` in your code at the moment of the crash? I suspect that the code you have displayed is in a method of a some class, and that method is invoked upon a null or otherwise invalid pointer.

Comment: @alownx : How do some programmers not know what language they're coding in?

Comment: @alownx, your issues with operator `<<` and `cout` make me think something is going *really* wrong in your program. A possible explanation would be that some part of your code is corrupting the heap, or that (less likely) something is actually able to overwrite `"and this is the end"` with garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippets are very incomplete, but when I fill in the blanks with what I think might make sense, it runs fine for me.....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string outMsg;
    std::string trans_str = ("</TRANSACTION>");
    int32_t position;

    std::string request = "abcdefg</TRANSACTION>hijklmnop";

    //Assign outMsg and find "</TRANSACTION>"
    outMsg.assign(request);
    position = outMsg.rfind(trans_str);

    std::string variable = outMsg.substr(position, outMsg.size()-position);

    std::cout << "This is a string\n" << variable << "\nand this is the end\n"; //this is an example
}
```

Comment: They are very incomplete because what you have above it pretty much what is going on. It just returns the position of "</TRANSACTION>". It compiles fine, but doesn't not run past the rfind(...). The last version ran fine, and the method has not changed. It's still passed a valid string. Short of memory issues, the changes made _should_ be irrelevent, which is why we are baffled.

Comment: @alownx: If you remove your changes again, does it start to work again? If, so can you add you changes back in piece by piece until you find the piece that causes it to fail.

Comment: @alownx - Sounds like you have a garbage writer... somebody using a stale pointer, or an uninitialized pointer, or indexing past the end of their array, or something like that.  Those are "fun" to find.  The bad thing is they can be "Heisenbugs" so their effects aren't necessarily consistent as you make changes to try to find them.  I'm guessing that somebody is garbage-writing onto one of the std::string objects (or some other object) that you're working with, and you don't know until later when you try to use the damaged object, which probably contains pointers/references that are corrupted.

Comment: ...Though it may not continue to exhibit the bug if you move the "offending" code (the std::cout line), you could try moving it up in your call tree to see where it starts working, and perhaps that will give you an idea what code branch to take in looking for the garbage writer.  Another (different) debugging option:  If you're using a debugger with hardware data-access breakpoints available, if you can determine exactly what location is being garbage-written, you MIGHT be able to set a data-access breakpoint there & catch the bad guy red-handed.

Comment: I'm wondering if your trans_str is the object getting stomped on... not the CONTENT of trans_str, but the management portion of it (the std::string object itself, not the string it manages, which is normally in a separate part of memory).  To check that, try cout'ing trans_str at the point you're calling rfind().  If that also crashes, then almost certainly it's trans_str that's getting garbage-written to.